# Why do only val type objects have component functions in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin for Android. I am using data class. I am trying to use component functions of data class. What I have observed is I get component functions for the variable only if the variable is of type "val" and I don't get them for "var"

```
  var customObj: CustomObj = CustomObj("Henlo", 5)
    mlist.add(customObj)
    for ((i, v) in mlist.withIndex()) {
        //print("In loop")
       // customObj.
        if(mlist.get(i) is CustomObj)
        println(mlist.get(i))
    }
```

for the above object customObj I do not get access to component functions.

If I change it to

```
  val customObj: CustomObj = CustomObj("Henlo", 5)
    mlist.add(customObj)
    for ((i, v) in mlist.withIndex()) {
        //print("In loop")
       // customObj.
        if(mlist.get(i) is CustomObj)
        println(mlist.get(i))
    }
```

I get access to component functions.

Edit: I am posting complete activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mlist = mutableListOf<Any>()
    var mlistNew = mutableListOf<String>()
    //var i = Int
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /*  val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
          println("Hey!! I am array Example" + numbers[2])*/
        mlist.add("this")
        mlist.add("is")
        mlist.add("my")
        mlist.add("first")
        mlist.add("kotlin")
        mlist.add("sample")
        mlist.add(1)
        mlist.add(2)
        mlist.add(3)
        mlist.add(4)
        mlist.add(5)
        mlist.add(CustomObj("my", 2))
        val customObj: CustomObj = CustomObj("Henlo", 5)
        mlist.add(customObj)
        for ((i, v) in mlist.withIndex()) {
            //print("In loop")
           // customObj.i
            if(mlist.get(i) is CustomObj)
            println(customObj.i)
        }
        //   mlist.get(0)
        for ((index, value) in mlistNew.withIndex()) {
            //   mlistNew.get(index)
        }
        mlistNew.add("one")
        mlistNew.add("two")

        // mlistNew.get(0)
    }

    private data class CustomObj(var i: String, var j: Int) : Any() {


    }
}
```

So my question is please let me know if my understanding is correct ?
If yes why is it so because it is very easy to access component functions if the number of parameters are less.

Thank you :)

Comment: please share your `component` and `component functions`

Comment: @PhanVanLinh  I am not getting you . Its a simple data class
 private data class CustomObj(var i: String, var j: Int) : Any() {


    }

Comment: You can use generated componentN functions on a data class object, it doesn't matter if the object is stored in var or val.

Comment: @Adam then am I doing something wrong ?? coz when I try to do alt tab for type var then it doesn't give me any option for component1() or so in android studio !!!

Comment: @Pritish do your question mean, if you use `var`, you can not access like `customObj.i`. if yes, please share your screen image with error since currently I dont have error

Comment: @PhanVanLinh No , there are inbuilt component methods in data class, provided by kotlin . so component1() is supposed to be the first parameter ie obj.i . I can access i this way,but not the inbuilt component function if I use var

Comment: @Pritish thank you, I don't know about it. However I just tested, I can access to `component1()` method by using `val` or `var`

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I have posted my complete activity class, please have a look.

Comment: @Pritish using `var` and I see there is no error https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q5pT.png

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I got it. its something really funny. When I press alt tab it initially gives me only three options, but when I type the complete word it starts giving me the component option but not the earlier three options :) :)

Comment: @Pritish Happy coding :))

Comment: Thank you fellas :)

Comment: Data class can't be inner class. Please ref: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html  -> Data classes cannot be abstract, open, sealed or inner;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a funny error due to android studio. I don't know how to describe it. But when I use var and press alt+tab initially it won't give any option for component() function among the list. Then I filter it down with "comp" it stats showing only 2 options like copy() and hash code, but still no component option,its only when I write the whole word "component" it removes all the earlier options and show only component() options but not the earlier ones . Same is not the case when I use val :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var pair = Pair("hi", "there")
    //val pair = Pair("hi", "there") // is the same

    val (hi , _) = pair
    println(hi + " " + pair.component2())
}
```

There should be no difference storing in var or val. Maybe something is missing, you omitted your custom data class, maybe something is wrong in there.

Comment: I have posted the complete activity now, please have a look